# Appending to a list vs concatenating in python recursive calls

Tags: python, list, recursion, append, concatenation

Please look at the following leetcode problem: 
https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/

In it, you're trying to generate a series of parentheses with a couple of rules how each list of parenthesis should look like.

I am aware of two approaches, that seem functionally identical to me but only one works. I understand that append returns None and modifies in-place, but I fail to see how that affects the recursive process.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
class Solution:
    def generate(self, output, temp, n):
            if len(temp) == 2*n:
                output.append(temp)
            left_count = temp.count("(")
            right_count = temp.count(")")
            if left_count < right_count:
                return
            if left_count < n:
                self.generate(output, temp.append("("), n)
            if left_count > right_count:
                self.generate(output, temp.append(")"), n)


    def generateParenthesis(self, n: int) -> List[str]:      
        output = []
        self.generate(output, ["("], n)
        return output
```

This code (using concat) works:

```
class Solution:
    def generate(self, output, temp, n):
            if len(temp) == 2*n:
                output.append(temp)

            left_count = temp.count("(")
            right_count = temp.count(")")
            if left_count < right_count:
                return
            if left_count < n:
                self.generate(output, temp + "(", n)
            if left_count > right_count:
                self.generate(output, temp + ")", n)

    def generateParenthesis(self, n: int) -> List[str]:      
        output = []
        self.generate(output, "", n)
        return output
```

Could someone please clarify what I'm missing here? Thank you very much.

Comment: In the first code, you use `temp.append("(")` as an argument, but you want to append to temp first and then use themp as an arg. `.append()` does not return the appended list, it modifies it.

Comment: "but I fail to see how that affects the recursive process." You fail to see how passing `None` as the `temp` argument in your recursive process will affect things?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, that's pretty rude. I'm missing the link between how it being modified in-place affects recursion. When you describe it like that, yes, that makes sense, but it's not 100% clear to me.

Comment: @pythonappend I'm trying to guide you to understanding. Forget about modification in-place, that is only related to the method returning `None` as a *convention*, one that isn't some hard and fast rule. Just think, `.append` returns `None`, that should make it clear.

Comment: Going forward, I'll use that rule, but right now I'm being a little manic in trying to get at the details. Thank you lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.append` returns `None` instead of the appended list as one could expect. You want to add the parenthesis to `temp` first and then use the "updated" `temp` as an argument.

```
class Solution:
    def generate(self, output, temp, n):
            if len(temp) == 2*n:
                output.append(temp)

            left_count = temp.count("(")
            right_count = temp.count(")")
            if left_count < right_count:
                return
            if left_count < n:
                temp.append("(") # does not return anything but modifies temp.
                self.generate(output, temp, n)
            if left_count > right_count:
                temp.append(")") # same.
                self.generate(output, temp, n)


    def generateParenthesis(self, n: int) -> List[str]:      
        output = []
        self.generate(output, ["("], n)
        return output
```

Comment: Why does modifying temp outside of the recursive call avoid the problem? Can't I just say (re your code) that .append doesn't return anything so this also wouldn't work? I'm making a bad argument but it's because I'm missing a link in my logic chain

Comment: It avoids the problem because `temp` is modified AND passed as an argument. Your first code was equivalent to calling `self.generate(output, None, n)`.

Comment: @pythonappend because `.append` doesn't return nothing, *every Python function always returns some object*. That object, for `.append`, is `None`, which is what you are passing to your recursive call. Obviously, that shouldn't work. So, it is equivalent to doing `temp.append('('); self.generate(output, None, n)`

Comment: ok, dumb example: in your code, can't I just say that temp.append("(") returns None, which is then passed into the recursive call? versus my approach (bear with me) which immediately passes None into the recursive call?

Comment: Yes, in my code `temp.append("(")` returns `None`, but what I pass in the recursive call is the (now appended) `temp` not `None`. Notice how I never even assign or use the returned value. You can think of the line `temp.append("(")` as `throwaway_variable = temp.append(")")`.

Comment: Alternatively, think of the line `temp.append("(")` as `temp = temp + ["("]`. That's clearer. The line *did some work* on an existing variable but it doesn't need to return anything.

Comment: @pythonappend Glad it helped you ;-)